# Shortest unique subsequence that distinguish a set of strings

Tags: arrays, algorithm, substring, subset, bit

I have N strings of bits (each of size M) X1[0..M], ..., XN[0..M]. I need the pseudocode/algorithm to find the smallest length subsequence (not necessarily contiguous) that is unique in each given string. For example,

If the strings are 011011, 011000, 010010 , the subsequence [2,4] (11, 10, 01) is different in each string. Or the subsequence [2, 4, 5] (111, 100, 010) . Or the subsequence [4, 5] (11, 00, 10).
But not the subsequence [0, 1, 5] (011, 010, 010) ---> Not unique in each string.

EDIT : `1 <= M <= 1000, 2 <= N <= 10`.
EDIT : Currently, my solution is this :
The minimum length of subsequence will range between `ceil(log2(N))` and `N-1`. 
 So, the pseudocode will be :

```
for i = ceil(log2(N)) to N-1 :  
    check all subsequence of size i
    if any subsequence distinguish all N strings, return i
```

The first step can be done by generating all combinations mCi.
The second step can be done by extracting the subsequence for all N strings and checking if all of them are distinct.
But this algorithm is currently exponential complexity. I wanted to know if a better algorithm is possible.

EDIT : No, It isn't homework. It was asked in an interview.

Comment: Whats the application for this? Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this would work:

first:

```
create matriz A (mxm) and array B(m)
for each bit i from right to left, compute de decimal value of j word in A[i][j]
//that means A[i][j] holds the decimal value of word j until the i bit
in the same loop B[i] will hold if bit i from all words are the same.
```

if B[i] = true, it means that we dont need to look that position, cos it says nothing.

```
create deque D//to check if there is equal elements
create array C(m)
for each position P in [0...M] where B[i] = false :


for each bit i = P ... 0

   for each word j
        C[j] = C[j]*2 + word[j][i] //word[j][i] = word j in bit i

    bool finished = true;
    for each e in C:
        if(D.count(e) > 0) {
             finished = false;
             break;
        }
        else{
            D.add(e)
        }
    }
    if(finished) return range(P...i);
    D.clear()

not possible;
```

what this algorithm does is: starting from useful positions, it starts creating value for words from them, and in the moment you are able to add all of them in the deque (all of them are different), you are done finding a range where they differ (range is P - i + 1 sized).

You have to run this anyway for all i where B[i] = false, so in the worst case it should run about n³.

Note that there are some optimizations that can be done knowing the number of strings and their size, for example: if there are 10 strings of size 3, you know its impossible to distinguish (cos there arent different 10 different binaries of size 3).  Given the number of strings, you can search only for (contiguous or not) sizes ceil(log(number of strings)). For example, 5 words cant differ in one bit, also they cant differ in 2 bits, but with 3 bits they can differ.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 2 queries - 1) Is A matrix same as word matrix? 2) It appears that this answer only consider contiguous ranges of bits. I need an algorithm that can also considers subsets of bits too . For example, if M = 6, then one subset could be bit 0,2,5 or 1,3 or 0,2,4,5, etc.

Comment: word matrix means a vector V where V[i] = word i. You can do something like discovering every column where all the values are not equal, then you count the minimum number of columns necessary to differ all words and then you can start building numbers out from the bits until all of them differ.